# Is the question "what lies behind your thinking?" a valid and natural phrase when I want to ask why someone has a particular opinion on something?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the question *what lies behind your thinking* a valid and natural phrase when I want to ask why someone has a particular opinion on something or caused them to think in a particular way? For example:

> You said that the team is going to lose. **What lies behind your thinking**?

Comment: It's a metaphor. The thinking is in the front, where everybody can see and understand it (fat chance, but this is a metaphor, not reality). The question is what _lies behind_ the thinking, which can't be seen and understood since it's hidden (_behind_). As for whether it's natural, it's pretty fancy for asking about one sports game; probly you'd want to save it for a serious discussion like metaphysics or topology, where there really is stuff behind the thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is valid and natural. It is equivalent to "Why do you think so?", which is a bit terse. You also might say just "Why?", which would be rather brusque.

When you ask why someone thinks something, you are challenging them. You may be able to do that more gently by using more words to ask the question.